# Change "logged in as a <username>" link in comments form

Tags: users, comment-form

I want to change the  "logged in as " link that displays in the reply comments form if logged in. The link is leading to wordpress profile in the backend, which it shouldn't. I want it to just a paragraph instead of an a tag . However i can't fint anywhere to change it, as there is not customizable template as far as i know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to rebuild the HTML through the [`comment_form_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_logged_in/) filter, where the HTML is constructed by default as:

```
'<p class="logged-in-as">' . sprintf(
/* translators: 1: edit user link, 2: accessibility text, 3: user name, 4: logout URL */
     __( '<a href="%1$s" aria-label="%2$s">Logged in as %3$s</a>. <a href="%4$s">Log out?</a>' ),
     get_edit_user_link(),
     /* translators: %s: user name */
     esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Logged in as %s. Edit your profile.' ), $user_identity ) ),
     $user_identity,
     wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) )
 ) . '</p>'
```

But since it's rather complex and we might loose the translations, when rebuilding it, we might try to replace it (once) instead with e.g.:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_logged_in', function( $html, $commenter, $user_identity )
{
  return preg_replace( '#<a href="[^"]*" aria-label="[^"]*">([^<]*)</a>#', '$1', $html, 1);
}, 10, 3 );
```

or with a DomDocument approach. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6778209/2078474).

Note that if the translation string changes in core, this might need adjustments!

Comment: Thank you! That fixed. Just as you seem to be knowledged: do you have a snippet to check if there is a breadcrumb trail shown or not?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Maybe better served as a new question. @MagnusPilegaard